# How to combine data from different columns from different databases from different vendors into one table?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, oracle, integration

Say i have a table named tbl1 in mysql :-

```
bookid int
name varchar(20)
price int
categoryid int
```

And then i have a 2nd table, tbl2 in Oracle :-

```
pubid int
name varchar(20)
addr varchar(50)
```

I want to combine these two into MS Sql Server 2008 named tbl3 whose structure should be :-

```
bookid int
name varchar(20)
price int
pubid int
name varchar(20)
```

Note that i know the tables are not meaningful but i just need the concept whether this thing is possible or not. And if yes then how? Which queries should i write? I don't want to use Sql Server Integration Services.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why don't you want to use SSIS? I ask simply because that's exactly the kind of thing for which it was designed.

Comment: Because i want to know the queries that one would write in absence of SSIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need something that can communicate with each of the databases. If SQL Server is the desination, and you don't want to use DTS/SSIS, then you could use Linked Servers. The only question is how the data from Oracle relates to the data from MySQL since there is no matching column. Regardless, persuming you had a Linked Server called "ORACLESERVER" and another called "MYSQLSEVER", you could do something like (assuming that `name` was the linking column):

```
Insert SqlServerDbName.SchemaName.TableName(....)
Select ...
From ORACLESERVER.DbName.SchemaName.tbl1 As T1
    Join MYSQLSERVER.DbName.SchemaName.tbl2 As T2
        On T2.name = T1.name
```

Another solution would be to use [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) to achieve a similar result.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for replying. But what if there is no join condition? I just want the records to appear side by side. For eg. row 1 of table3 should contain row 1 of table1 and table2. Similarly row 2 of table3 should contain row 2 of  table1 and table2.

Comment: @Nitesh Panchal - Without a common column, how would you determine which for a given of say Oracle data, which row(s) from the MySQL should go with it? If you want them side by side, you *must* have something to join them.

Answer (score 0):

Do they have a common column that you can run a join on. For example does the categoryid in the first table match the pubid in the second. Does name from table1 match with name in table2. If so is name the key, no other book with have the same name with each other. If so run a join on the tables using name as the common key.

If there is no common key then you can do `select * from table1, table2, ..., tablen`. This would work into a really large table. If you join two tables with 12 rows each then your resulting table would have `12*12 = 144` rows in total.

Comment: Hi Kyra, there is no common column. What to do in this case?